# How do I create a 'sticky' horizontal scrolling effect with collection view Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with multiple cells. Users can scroll horizontality. However, I want it to center the nearest cell once the user lets go. Or, if not, have some form of paging but for individual cells. I'm making basically an icon/profile picture picker.

```
@IBOutlet weak var profilePicScrollView: UIScrollView!
var profilePicsArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "sample_user_photo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings_icon"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "usernametextfield_dark")]

@IBOutlet weak var profilePicCollectionView: UICollectionView!


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return profilePicsArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionat section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageViewCellReuseID", for: indexPath) as! SettingsCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageInCollection.image =  profilePicsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageInCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor.getRandomColor()

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your collection view's cells are equal to the width of your collection view's bounds, you could just set the collection view's `isPagingEnabled` property to true – considering `UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`.

If that's not the case, then you might try the following:

First, implement the `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:willDecelerate:)` method of your collection view's delegate. Then, in that method's body, determine which cell in `collectionView.visibleCells` is most visible by comparing each of their centers against your collection view's center. Once you find your collection view's most visible cell, scroll to it by calling `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)`.

Comment: I was actually just in the process of trying that! I'm stuck on how to get the relative position of each cell in the parent collection view (i.e. scroll view since inheritance). I tried frame, bounds, center.x, nothing seems to return the current position...